# i am trying to bind the details of an object in a component but i am unable to capture the object?

Tags: angular2-template

in the component if i try to do console.log(patient) is see a xml represented object is coming into my console but if i try to bind the data in my component from the returned object i am unable to for suppose in my component in the template section i am doing {{patient.Patient_Name}} but i am unable to see the data in the  component?

`@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-thumbnail',
    template: <h2>Name:{{patients.Patient_Name}}</h2>`

})

`export class DashboardThumbnailComponent {
patients : Patient
constructor(private  dashboardService : DashboardService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}`


`ngOnInit(){
this.dashboardService.getPatient(+this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((patient) => {
          this.patients.Patient_Name = patient.Patient_Name;`enter code here
         `console.log(patient);
         })
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand after lot of research that the return type of my getPatient method is an array so to bind the data i had to loop through the patients object instead of directly binding it. hope this helps!!

```
enter code here<div *ngFor = "let patient of patients" class = "well hoverwell thumbnail" >
 <h2>Name : {{patient.Patient_Name}}</h2>
```